# Three.js: attach object to camera but not make it rotate with it

Tags: javascript, three.js

I currently have a SphereGeometry attached to a Perspective Camera. But when I rotate the camera, the Sphere rotates with the camera which is normal but in my case I do not want that.

Here is what I have:

```
camera.add(Sphere);
Sphere.position.set (0, -100, 0);
```

What I want is to attach the sphere to the bottom of the camera but stay in that position. Currently, when I rotate the camera, the Sphere seems to rotate with it so I cannot see it. How can I attach the child object in a way that does not rotate with the camera? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One approach is to define an `onBeforeRender()` method for your sphere mesh. For example:

```
scene.add( sphere ); // add it as a child of the scene, not the camera

sphere.onBeforeRender = function( renderer, scene, camera, geometry, material, group ) {
    var pos = camera.position;
    this.position.set( pos.x, pos.y - 100, pos.z );
};
```

three.js r.86